# Dequeue implementation error in Java

Tags: java, deque

I tried to implement a Dequeue.

Below is part of my code. I used print() function in order to print all nodes in Dequeue, but it seems that the nodes are not connected at all.

The addLast() function tries to new a node at connect into Dequeue.

```
public class Test<Item>{

    private Node first, last;
    private int N;
    private class Node{
        Item value;
        Node next;
    }

    public void addLast(Item item){
        Node oldLast = last;
        Node last = new Node();
        last.value = item;
        last.next = oldLast;
        N++;
    }

    public void print(){
        Node temp = last;
        while(temp != null){
            System.out.println(temp.value);
            temp = temp.next;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Test<String> deque = new Test<String>();
        deque.addLast("hello");
        deque.addLast("first");
        deque.addLast("second");
        deque.addLast("third");
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your print() code

Comment: Hi, I edit my previous code

Comment: Can't tell anything without your Node class.  Must not be setting the next reference properly.

Comment: I have my Node class, which is private

Comment: @duffmo inner Node class in code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `addLast()` method:

Instead of `Node last = new Node();` you should write:

```
last = new Node();
```